# clear: right with <span>

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following HTML markup:

```
<td class="title">
    <img src="my-image.png" class="thumbnail" />
    <span class="name">Product 1 Name</span>
    <span class="code">EA-55</span>
</td>
```

I would like to float the thumbnail to the left, and then display each span on a newline next to it. So the output should look something like this:

```
+------+ Product 1 Name
| img  | EA-55
+------+
```

I have floated both `span` elements left, and added `clear: right` to `span.name`. However, this seems to have no effect. Here's the CSS:

Can anyone explain why the `clear: right` is seemingly being ignored by Chrome?

```
table.basket tbody td img.thumbnail {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
table.basket tbody td span.name,
table.basket tbody td span.code {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
table.basket tbody td span.name {
    clear: right
}
```

Comment: `then display each span on a newline next to it.` Why do you want to use `span` and not `div`?

Comment: I know the workarounds, I am curious as to why the solution I posted doesn't work, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `clear: right` will clear the span below anything floated to the right. You have nothing floated to the right, only to the left. Floated content doesn't take up space. Each floated element gets stacked on top of other floated elements in the same direction until space runs out on the line. You can't clear things that are stacked on top of it "to the right." You can only clear **all** elements which are **floated to the right**.

It sounds to me like the `.name` and `.code` spans don't need to be floated at all if you just want them on their own line. Try removing the float from them and leaving them as `display: block`. [See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ua2yp/3/)